# Javascript: Loop Through Object By Number Index Rather Than Key-Value

Tags: javascript, loops, object, nested

While looping through an object is simple using `for(key in object)`, I'd like to access an object via an index (like an array) rather than its value.

I have a "days of the week" object composed of:

```
days: { sunday: "N", monday: "Y", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "Y", 
thursday: "N", friday: "Y", saturday: "N" }
```

I want to use a for-loop which cycles through the seven days of the week (0-6) and checks whether the object is "Y" or "N" for that day (checking the "days" object for the value at key 0 (sunday), 1 (monday), 2, 3, etc.)

```
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) { }
```

My problem could be solved with a bunch of `if` statements `if i == 0 { //check sunday } else if i == 1 { //check monday }` or manipulating my object into multiple arrays and going from there, however neither of these are very elegant.  Is there a way to loop through the `days` object and access each value by a key (0 for first, 1 for second, etc.)?

Comment: Order cannot be guaranteed. You could use `Object.keys(daysObject)` for collecting all the day properties in an array, and after that you could iterate over it. Again, I am saying order cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: Javascript objects are maps, which by definition, are not indexed.

Comment: what about an array for the keys?

Comment: @NinaScholz That's what I'm working on using at the moment. I wasn't sure if there was an elegant way to do it as I described, and am hoping there still is - but for now, I'll be manipulating it into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate over the properties of an object in a consistent order,
you have no choice but to use an array of the property names,
for example:

```
var daysList = [ 'sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday' ];
```

And then you can iterate over the array of names:

```
for (let i = 0; i < daysList.length; i++) {
    let day = daysList[i];
    // do what you need with days[day]
}
```

Comment: It does indeed seem that there is no way to do what I wanted in the manner I desired.

Comment: not quite as elegant as this i guess...but another way is `Map`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

```js
const days = { sunday: "N", monday: "Y", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "Y", 
thursday: "N", friday: "Y", saturday: "N" }

const map = new Map(Object.entries(days));
var mapIter = map.entries();

x = 0;
while(x < Object.keys(days).length) {
  let next = mapIter.next().value
  if(next[1] == 'Y') {
    console.log(next[0] + " is Y");
  }
  else if(next[1] == 'N') {
    console.log(next[0] + " is N");
  }
  x++;
}
```

Comment: `Object.entries(days)` [does NOT guarantee the order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries): _"The Object.entries() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property [key, value] pairs, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well)."_

Comment: seems like it maintains order to me...look at the code snippet

Comment: One code snippet does not prove it, sorry. The order of `for...in` [is NOT determined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) in JavaScript, even though many browsers preserve the order: _"A `for...in` loop iterates over the properties of an object in an arbitrary order"_.